# JavaScript How can I replace a char from a String with 2 new chars

Tags: javascript, string, replace, char

For instance, I have the string "Hello my name is ..." and now I want to change the string to "Hellel my name is ...". How am I supposed to do that? I already wrote a Code but anytime I wanna change/replace 1 char with 2 new ones the whole "website" starts loading forever.

Here is my Code:

```
function f(str) {
        let e = document.getElementById("changeValue");
        let replaceStr = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
        const vokale = ['a', 'e',  'i', 'o', 'u'];
        for (let i = 0; i < str.length;i++) {
            if (vokale.includes(str.toLowerCase()[i])){
                if(vokale.includes(str.toLowerCase()[i+1])){
                    str = str.substr(0, i + 1) + '' + str.substr(i + 2, str.length);
                }
                if (replaceStr.length == 2) {
                    str = str.substr(0, i) + replaceStr.charAt(0) + str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
                    str = str.substr(0, i + 1) + replaceStr.charAt(1) + str.substr(i + 2, str.length);
                } else {
                    str = str.substr(0, i) + replaceStr + str.substr(i + 1, str.length);
                }
            }
        }
        changeText(str);
    }
```

str ... is the string i wanna to modify 
- e ... is just a string/char that i wanna replace something, like here i wanna replace all vocals with e.

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: How about str.replace?

Comment: Where are you adding the two new characters?

Comment: @DontrolAltDel Won't work for me(I guess) because I also want to change a to au and so I have a infinity-loop.

Comment: if you go backwards through the string the infinity-loop problem goes away

Comment: Not really, because If theres is a "u" I got the same problem, BTW changed the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to use regex with replace function:

```
let regex = '(a|e|i|o|u)'

let re = new RegExp(regex, 'g');

str = str.replace(re, replaceStr);
console.log(str)
```

In this case infinite loop doesn't happen and you could replace vocals with 2-3 or more characters

Comment: That works, thank you. Just for interest why is that not working? I really don't get it:D

Comment: every insertion in your code increases string lenght. When you replace 1 vocal with 2 another vocals, second one from replaced will be picked up by your loop and replaced again with 2 vocals. Idea is the following. Initial string: FAR. on 1st iteration you replace A with AU. Next symbol that will be processed is U that also will be replaced. on Second iteration result is FAUR -> FAAUR. Loop takes next symbol which is again vocal - FAAAUR etc. infinite loop :)

Comment: oh ... But keep in mine: "With great power comes great responsibility. I will only use regular expressions when there isn't a simpler way to accomplish the desired outcome. Because every time I abuse regular expressions, another programmer loses a weekend crying into his fourth Red Bull while trying to decipher the mess I've made." And thank you :)

Comment: Another idea that just come into my mind after your admonition: after replace increase loop counter by length of replace string